# How to dynamically set SSLCertificateFile for user's custom domains

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04

I have a site where users can point their own custom domain to their unique directory on my site through **A Records**.

For example, `example.com` points to `mysite.com/something` and `anothersite.org` points to `mysite.com/somethingelse`

Each of these custom domains has an SSL certificate generated for them however is there a way to point to them dynamically in the VirtualHost file?

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

`domain.com` should be the current domain - if someone visits `example.com` then that should be where `domain.com` is.

Is it possible to use variables somehow?

I have tried this but it doesn't work and causes an error:
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/%{HTTP_HOST}/fullchain.pem

There is one only virtual host in total as there are hundreds of custom domains.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @wiggles Can't remember exactly, but basically instead of having one virtual host file I had a separate one created dynamically for each domain.

Comment: That's what's I've gone with too

Comment: @wiggles There is hardly any information on this subject even though so many websites seem to have the feature. I am still unsure if the dynamic virtual hosts are efficient

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. I guess we'll have to find out the hard way